# Why did Anna Cathcart do this?

Tags: spy-game

During the 'Cathcart affair' portion of Muir's revelations in *Spy Game* we see the scene where him and Anna are at a party. He has suspicion that she's working with Stasi at this point and she very helpfully confirms that to him with the phrase 'are you bringing someone across?' (this is the same night Bishop is driving Schmidt to the border).

**Why did she do that? What was Muir's plan with her? Why was he sure that setting her up in that way with Schmidt part would prompt her to reveal herself?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited after seeing relevant scenes and noting the big differences from the earlier script to the movie:

TL;DR:

There's an earlier version of the script that explains more.

The movie has cut down on a lot of it, and just leaves the bare bones.

So, what we are left with is:

- Its her job as a mole to find out who is being smuggled out. She actually already has her suspicions but is looking for confirmation of when.
- Muir wanted to expose her, as he has his suspicions.
- Muir was sure she would do her job, radio in ASAP that Schmidt is on his way out now - in the movie it is because the way Muir looks at her - she has to leave quickly to radio this in. So quick goodbye kiss and leave the scene ASAP.
- at the checkpoint, Muir is proved right as they have a photo of Schmidt waiting to check for him (too fast for her to discover it is Schmidt - they know it is: they just didn't have the time, and now, from Ann, they do).
- and she is found murdered after her defection. (Though they try to burn Bishop for this - there is more to this in the early script, but again its all trimmed down). She is blown, so her handler removes her.
- ultimately, they sacrificed scene time and dialogue to reduce it to Muir's knowing look at Ann and her swift exit. Probably thought they were trimming the fat as Ann's death is just another reason to burn Bishop and doesn't add more to the movie beyond Bishops initial upset at being used.
- at first I thought they were keeping to her panicking (as in the early script), but the movie seems to infer that she has to report this quickly to be able to catch Schmidt instead, which is what catches her out, leading her to defect (only inferred again by her turning up dead in East Germany).
- Muir's planned phone call was for him to confirm his suspicions that Ann is the mole and to tell Bishop to abort because of this. They got what they needed anyway. Schmidt can burn.

(in retrospect, the script had Ann as weaker, and with less in the resulting movie, she looked stronger)

...................

Not seen it for  very long time so not a lot to go on:

Earlier in the movie:

> I think we were talking about Operation Rodeo.
>
> My East German contacts...
>
> ... discovered that we had  an unidentified mole in the embassy.
>
> And we had the Ambassador  in our cross hairs...
>
> ...until some information leaked when he was out the country.
>
> So that just left one possibility.
>
> Ann!

> ***Why did she do that?***

She is the mole. She is vulnerable and knows she is, and as a mole, is curious to see who is going across - and if its someone important..she might be exposed. So, she asks who it is. The result makes her panic, which was Muir's intention.

> ***What was Muir's plan with her?***

He already has his suspicions, he just wanted to shake the tree to see if he was right.

Schmidt was the bait. Muir knew that they were already compromised by a mole. He needed a legit op to see who it was, and if he was right.

> The op was bringing Schmidt across.
>
> It was to set up Cathcart.
>
> And your end had to look legit.
>
> Are you telling me Schmidt was bait?
>
> Yes.

> ***Why was he sure that setting her up in that way with Schmidt part would prompt her to reveal herself?***

Because Muir set Bishop up with a real job, a real target, anything else might raise suspicion. Schmidt was that unfortunate target. Ann duly reported Schmidt's impending defection.

Bishop had to go through the whole thing without a clue it was a set up, and the mole would have to believe that Schmidt was going across.

Muir adds:

> ...he told the Russians last week he had a contact... An American he could use.

and:

> the greater good. - That's exactly what it's about.
>
> Because what we do is, unfortunately, very necessary.
>
> If you can't sacrifice scum like Schmidt for those that only want their freedom...
>
> ...then you better take a hard look at your chosen profession.

In a different version of the script, Muir adds:

> Ann was a more important target. It's her fault your people got hit.

Earlier screenplay  (Also, Schmidt was originally Gridenko):

https://www.reddit.com/r/Screenwriting/comments/u81wp0/pdf_download_screenplay_of_spy_game_2001_by/

> I had my eye on her for about 6 months

> We can now see it in Ann Cathcart's face, hidden behind her elegant effort to show no emotion: Panic.
>
> "Frightened her into thinking she'd be identified. I figured her to run."

Comment: So you basically saying he was counting on her betraying her own secrecy due to fear that the person they're bringing across might?

That doesn't make too much sense given she's trading a possibility of discovery for a certainty. And also she didn't seem that scared during the scene (and the phrase) to me. More like as if she felt in control.

Comment: I'll find the earlier script to link to. They made some changes, the earlier version showed intent for her to panic. Maybe this was lost when they filmed it. Note that schmidt was originally Gridenko or something. But basically she wasnt supposed to be very good at being a mole, and just needed exposing to make her flee to East Germany, and ultimately her fate

Comment: https://youtu.be/3JohENOC4BY?si=YTKEU1miiff7kIe1&t=128 - just seen that they kind of blow over it, either he whispers the name or just smiles, and she doesn't outright look panicked, but she is moving off very suddenly. And thats a going away kiss. Anyway, the script says more than the movie does.

Comment: It does seem more plausible after an edit but still there's one more thing. She surely knew Muir was CIA, so wouldn't skipping the report (via radio) this time make more sense? She would fail at this particular task but would get to try again and bring in more info? You say 'Muir was sure she would do her job' but I will add that she 'also knew that he knew' so to say. She knew about the trap and still walked into it.

Comment: Sadly they don't really explain this. Clearly theres a bit of history, as she messes about with his wife history, but its not entirely clear what she knows, only that Muir has spent some time focused on her as the mole suspect - what she knows from her side is never explained. Her role in the film is merely to show Bishops feelings (re: Schmidt) and a reason to burn him, and then shes dispensed with (as a mole and in the movie).